# JavaScript Class: Dynamic Default Value

Tags: javascript, magento, knockout.js

Trying to set **creditCardExpMonth** to the current month in the below Magento 2 JavaScript class (cc-form.js). The option month values are 1-12. When I manually add a month value like 3 **creditCardExpMonth: 3,** to the defaults:{ }, it works as expected. I just can't seem to figure out how to set it to the current month dynamically. I'm open to any solution that allows for the value to be overridden by the user's selection but I'd prefer it be inside this class or on the html page and not a JQuery update after the page loads.

I created a getCurrentMonth() function in this class but couldn't figure out how to access it correctly to set creditCardExpMonth to a default value.

```
define(
[
    'underscore',
    'Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/credit-card-data',
    'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/credit-card-number-validator',
    'mage/translate'
],
function (_, Component, creditCardData, cardNumberValidator, $t) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            creditCardType: '',
            creditCardExpYear: '',
            creditCardExpMonth: '',
            creditCardNumber: '',
            creditCardSsStartMonth: '',
            creditCardSsStartYear: '',
            creditCardVerificationNumber: '',
            selectedCardType: null
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe([
                    'creditCardType',
                    'creditCardExpYear',
                    'creditCardExpMonth',
                    'creditCardNumber',
                    'creditCardVerificationNumber',
                    'creditCardSsStartMonth',
                    'creditCardSsStartYear',
                    'selectedCardType'
                ]);
            return this;
        },

        initialize: function() {
            var self = this;
            this._super();


            //Set credit card number to credit card data object
            this.creditCardNumber.subscribe(function(value) {
                var result;
                self.selectedCardType(null);

                if (value == '' || value == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                result = cardNumberValidator(value);

                if (!result.isPotentiallyValid && !result.isValid) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (result.card !== null) {
                    self.selectedCardType(result.card.type);
                    creditCardData.creditCard = result.card;
                }

                if (result.isValid) {
                    creditCardData.creditCardNumber = value;
                    self.creditCardType(result.card.type);
                }
            });

            //Set expiration year to credit card data object
            this.creditCardExpYear.subscribe(function(value) {
                creditCardData.expirationYear = value;
            });

            //Set expiration month to credit card data object
            this.creditCardExpMonth.subscribe(function(value) {
                creditCardData.expirationYear = value;
            });

            //Set cvv code to credit card data object
            this.creditCardVerificationNumber.subscribe(function(value) {
                creditCardData.cvvCode = value;
            });
        },

        getCode: function() {
            return 'cc';
        },
        getData: function() {
            return {
                'method': this.item.method,
                'additional_data': {
                    'cc_cid': this.creditCardVerificationNumber(),
                    'cc_ss_start_month': this.creditCardSsStartMonth(),
                    'cc_ss_start_year': this.creditCardSsStartYear(),
                    'cc_type': this.creditCardType(),
                    'cc_exp_year': this.creditCardExpYear(),
                    'cc_exp_month': this.creditCardExpMonth(),
                    'cc_number': this.creditCardNumber()
                }
            };
        },
        getCcAvailableTypes: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.availableTypes[this.getCode()];
        },
        getIcons: function (type) {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.icons.hasOwnProperty(type)
                ? window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.icons[type]
                : false
        },
        getCcMonths: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.months[this.getCode()];
        },
        getCcYears: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.years[this.getCode()];
        },
        hasVerification: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.hasVerification[this.getCode()];
        },
        hasSsCardType: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.hasSsCardType[this.getCode()];
        },
        getCvvImageUrl: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.cvvImageUrl[this.getCode()];
        },
        getCvvImageHtml: function() {
            return '<img src="' + this.getCvvImageUrl()
                + '" alt="' + $t('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')
                + '" title="' + $t('Card Verification Number Visual Reference')
                + '" />';
        },
        getSsStartYears: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.ccform.ssStartYears[this.getCode()];
        },
        getCcAvailableTypesValues: function() {
            return _.map(this.getCcAvailableTypes(), function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'type': value
                }
            });
        },
        getCcMonthsValues: function() {
            return _.map(this.getCcMonths(), function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'month': value.substring(0,2)
                }
            });
        },  
        getCcYearsValues: function() {
            return _.map(this.getCcYears(), function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'year': value
                }
            });
        },
        getCurrentMonth: function() {
            var d = new Date(); 
            var n = d.getMonth() + 1; 
            return n;
        },
        getCurrentYear: function() {
            var d = new Date(); 
            var n = d.getYear(); 
            return n;
        },
        getSsStartYearsValues: function() {
            return _.map(this.getSsStartYears(), function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'year': value
                }
            });
        },
        isShowLegend: function() {
            return false;
        },
        getCcTypeTitleByCode: function(code) {
            var title = '';
            _.each(this.getCcAvailableTypesValues(), function (value) {
                if (value['value'] == code) {
                    title = value['type'];
                }
            });
            return title;
        },
        formatDisplayCcNumber: function(number) {
            return 'xxxx-' + number.substr(-4);
        },
        getInfo: function() {
            return [
                {'name': 'Credit Card Type', value: this.getCcTypeTitleByCode(this.creditCardType())},
                {'name': 'Credit Card Number', value: this.formatDisplayCcNumber(this.creditCardNumber())}
            ];
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the knockout HTML with select data-bind just in case it's needed (taken from Magento payment cc-form.html):

```
<select  name="payment[cc_exp_month]"
                             class="select select-month"
                             data-bind="attr: {id: getCode() + '_expiration', 'data-container': getCode() + '-cc-month', 'data-validate': JSON.stringify({required:true, 'validate-cc-exp':'#' + getCode() + '_expiration_yr'})},
                                        enable: isActive($parents),
                                        options: getCcMonthsValues(),  
                                        optionsValue: 'value',
                                        optionsText: 'month',
                                        optionsCaption: $t('Month'),
                                        value: creditCardExpMonth">
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this script is run every time the page loads, you could do something like this:

```
defaults: {
            creditCardType: '',
            creditCardExpYear: '',
            creditCardExpMonth: (function(){
                                  return ((new Date()).getMonth()+1);
                                 })(),
            creditCardNumber: '',
            creditCardSsStartMonth: '',
            creditCardSsStartYear: '',
            creditCardVerificationNumber: '',
            selectedCardType: null
        }
```

or if you want something cleaner, you can refactor the code into a function that is defined prior to this object creation:

```
function (_, Component, creditCardData, cardNumberValidator, $t) {
    function getCurrentMonth() {
        return ((new Date()).getMonth()+1);
    }
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            creditCardType: '',
            creditCardExpYear: '',
            creditCardExpMonth: getCurrentMonth(),
            creditCardNumber: '',
            creditCardSsStartMonth: '',
            creditCardSsStartYear: '',
            creditCardVerificationNumber: '',
            selectedCardType: null
        },
```